# Native Handle of QMdiSubWindow

Tags: c++, qt, hwnd

I'm trying to get the HWND of a QMdiSubWindow which I added to a QMdiArea.

I used the following code to get the handle:

```
Dialog* subWindow = new Dialog(this);
QMdiSubWindow* sw = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(subWindow);
(HWND) hwnd = id->winId();
```

To test if it worked I used the following code:

```
SetWindowText(hwnd, "Hello, World!");
```

Nothing happens. If I run the following code:

```
 SetWindowText((HWND) this->winId(), "Hello, World!");
```

It works correctly for the main window. The code is placed in the constructor of the main window. The type of the subwindow class is QDialog.

Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Qt widgets if they are not top level windows.

Comment: I found out that this is possible by turing off alien widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have à correct `HWND` but it may actually not be the one you are looking for  (one visible window could actually be made of a few nested ones: you may believe you picked up the right one when you actually wish to pick up its child or parent).

I suggest that you use [Microsoft spy tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470407.aspx), use the [finder tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460750.aspx/) to select the mdi widget you are interested in (directly on your displayed GUI), spy tool will give you its `HWND`. Then you can check Qt reports you the same id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I turned off Qt Alien Widgets so that every widget is a nativ window. Afterwords I executed the same code as above and inspected the result with spy++. I saw that the title was changed in the window properties but the window title in the ui was not changed. Do you may know why?

Comment: Its probably just a refresh issue. Or, the window you changed the title is not the one shown as parent mdi window

Comment: If I run the same code for the mainwindow it doesn't need any kind of refresh so I don't think its necessary here. If I use spy++ to hover the window where the property change happened it hovers the correct window. I don't know how qt bypasses commands from the winapi..